# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: convert mm/dd/yyyy string to a date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

when i convert my string object in `mm/dd/yyyy` format to `Date` it gives me

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09/17/2014"
```

i am trying to do it like this :

```
String date= "09/17/2014";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
Date journeyDate= (java.sql.Date) df.parse(date);
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and the two `Date` classes. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several potential problems here:

- You're not specifying a format
- You're not specifying a locale
- You're not specifying a time zone
- You're trying to cast the return value (which will be a `java.util.Date` reference) to a `java.sql.Date` - that would fail

You want something like:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
df.setTimeZone(...); // Whatever time zone you want to use
Date journeyDate = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(text).getTime());
```

Comment: Hi Jon month cannot be 17 you need to switch it even though +1 for the nice explanation

Comment: @SparkOn: Whoops - fixed, thanks. Misread the question for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date journeyDate = df.parse(date); // gives you java.util.Date
```

If you want java.sql.Date then

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(journeyDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following exception:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

```
System.out.println("inside the XMLGregorianCalendar");

sb = (String) map.get(fieldname);
System.out.println("THis is XMLGReogoriaaaaan calendar"+ sb);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
Date journeyDate = new java.sql.Date(df.parse(sb).getTime());
System.out.println("this"+journeyDate);
```

Comment: was that a answer or is this a problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed `m` and `M`.

`m`stands for minute and `M` for month.

Below is an example of a working format.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateInString = "07/06/2013"; 
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for you date work. You can directly pass a `java.time.LocalDate` to your SQL database via JDBC (since JDBC 4.2) or JPA (for example since Hibernate 5.0).

You need to specify which format to assume for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The rest is straightforward:

```
    String date = "09/17/2014";
    LocalDate journeyDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DATE_FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(journeyDate);
```

Output:

> 2014-09-17

I assumed that you were trying to specify that you wanted a `java.sql.Date` because you needed it for use with an SQL database. But you don’t need no `java.sql.Date` for that. For how to insert a `LocalDate` into SQL, see the link at the bottom.

If you need a `java.sql.Date` for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time right now, the conversion is straightforward too:

```
    java.sql.Date oldfashionedJavaSqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(journeyDate);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedJavaSqlDate);
```

> 2014-09-17

### What happened in your code?

Jon Skeet has already pointed out the issues with your code. But only out of curiosity, more precisely, what happened? The no-arg `SimpleDateFormat` constructor gives you a localized format for date and time in your default locale. For example for `en-IN` locale the format could be like `17/09/14, 12:00 AM`. In this case your formatter would parse 09 as the day of month, 17 as the month and 2014 as the year and then complaint with the exception because the comma and time were not present in the string.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)