# Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc, h2

How to insert and fetch [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types such as [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) via [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to an SQL database such as the [H2 Database Engine](http://h2database.com/)?

The old way using [`PreparedStatement::setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-) and [`ResultSet::getDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate-int-) works for the legacy [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) type. I want to avoid using these troublesome old date-time classes.

What is the modern way for sending java.time types through a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We have two routes to exchanging java.time objects through JDBC:

- **JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers**
  If your JDBC driver complies with the [JDBC 4.2 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr221/JDBC4.2MR-January2014.pdf) or later, you can deal directly with the java.time objects.
- **Older drivers, before JDBC 4.2**
  If your JDBC driver does not yet comply with JDBC 4.2 or later, then you briefly convert your java.time objects to their equivalent java.sql type or vice-versa. Look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

The legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and the related `java.sql` classes such as `java.sql.Date` are an awful mess. Built with a poorly-designed hacked approach,  they have proven to be flawed, troublesome, and confusing. Avoid them whenever possible. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

## JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers

The built-in JDBC driver for H2 (as of 2017-03) appears to comply with JDBC 4.2.

Compliant drivers are now aware of the java.time types. But rather than adding `setLocalDate`/`getLocalDate` sorts of methods, the JDBC committee added [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)/[`getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-) methods.

To send data to the database, simply pass your java.time object to `PreparedStatement::setObject`. The Java type of your passed argument is detected by the driver and converted to the appropriate SQL type. A Java `LocalDate` is converted to a SQL `DATE` type. See section 22 of [JDBC Maintenance Release 4.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr221/JDBC4.2MR-January2014.pdf) PDF document for a list of these mappings.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject ( 1 , myLocalDate ); // Automatic detection and conversion of data type.
```

To retrieve data from the database, call `ResultSet::getObject`. Rather than casting the resulting `Object` object, we can pass an extra argument, the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) of the data type we expect to receive. By specifying the expected class, we gain [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) checked and verified by your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) and compiler.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject ( "my_date_column_" , LocalDate.class );
```

Here is an entire working example app showing how to insert and select `LocalDate` values into an H2 database.

```
package com.example.h2localdate;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App ( );
        app.doIt ( );
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        try {
            Class.forName ( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }

        try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ( "jdbc:h2:mem:trash_me_db_" ) ;
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        ) {
            String tableName = "test_";
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (\n" +
                "  id_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
                "  date_ DATE NOT NULL\n" +
                ");";
            stmt.execute ( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO test_ ( date_ ) " + "VALUES (?) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ; ) {
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
                preparedStatement.setObject ( 1, today.minusDays ( 1 ) );  // Yesterday.
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
                preparedStatement.setObject ( 1, today );                  // Today.
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
                preparedStatement.setObject ( 1, today.plusDays ( 1 ) );   // Tomorrow.
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM test_";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next ( ) ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = rs.getObject ( "id_", UUID.class );  // Pass the class to be type-safe, rather than casting returned value.
                    LocalDate localDate = rs.getObject ( "date_", LocalDate.class );  // Ditto, pass class for type-safety.

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println ( "id_: " + id + " | date_: " + localDate );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> id_: e856a305-41a1-45fa-ab69-cfa676285461 | date_: 2017-03-26

> id_: a4474e79-3e1f-4395-bbba-044423b37b9f | date_: 2017-03-27

> id_: 5d47bc3d-ebfa-43ab-bbc2-7bb2313b33b0 | date_: 2017-03-28

## Non-compliant drivers

For H2, the code shown above is the road I recommend you take. But FYI, for other databases that do not comply yet with JDBC 4.2, I can show you how to briefly convert between java.time and java.sql types. This kind of conversion code certainly runs on H2 as I show below, but doing so is silly now that we have the simpler approach shown above.

To send data to the database, convert your `LocalDate` to a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object using new methods added to that old class.

```
java.sql.Date mySqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( myLocalDate );
```

Then pass to the `PreparedStatement::setDate` method.

```
preparedStatement.setDate ( 1, mySqlDate );
```

To retrieve from the database, call `ResultSet::getDate` to obtain a `java.sql.Date` object.

```
java.sql.Date mySqlDate = myResultSet.getDate( 1 );
```

Then immediately convert to a `LocalDate`. You should handle the java.sql objects as briefly as possible. Do all your business logic and other work using only the java.time types.

```
LocalDate myLocalDate = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Here is an entire example app showing this use of java.sql types with java.time types in an H2 database.

```
package com.example.h2localdate;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App ( );
        app.doIt ( );
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        try {
            Class.forName ( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }

        try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ( "jdbc:h2:mem:trash_me_db_" ) ;
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ( ) ;
        ) {
            String tableName = "test_";
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (\n" +
                "  id_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
                "  date_ DATE NOT NULL\n" +
                ");";
            stmt.execute ( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO test_ ( date_ ) " + "VALUES (?) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement ( sql ) ; ) {
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) );
                preparedStatement.setDate ( 1, java.sql.Date.valueOf ( today.minusDays ( 1 ) ) );  // Yesterday.
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
                preparedStatement.setDate ( 1, java.sql.Date.valueOf ( today ) );  // Today.
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
                preparedStatement.setDate ( 1, java.sql.Date.valueOf ( today.plusDays ( 1 ) ) );  // Tomorrow.
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate ( );
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM test_";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next ( ) ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = ( UUID ) rs.getObject ( "id_" );  // Cast the `Object` object to UUID if your driver does not support JDBC 4.2 and its ability to pass the expected return type for type-safety.
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = rs.getDate ( "date_" );
                    LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate ();  // Immediately convert into java.time. Mimimize use of java.sql types.

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println ( "id_: " + id + " | date_: " + localDate );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
    }
}
```

For fun let's try another. This time [using a `DataSource` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) from which to get a connection. And this time trying [`LocalDate.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN) which is a constant for about a billion years ago in ISO 8601, -999999999-01-01.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.UUID;

public class LocalDateMin
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        LocalDateMin app = new LocalDateMin();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ()
    {
        org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource ds = new org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource();
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:localdate_min_example_db_;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );

        try (
                Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        )
        {
            String tableName = "test_";
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (\n" +
                    "  id_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY ,\n" +
                    "  date_ DATE NOT NULL\n" +
                    ");";
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO test_ ( date_ ) " + "VALUES (?) ;";
            try ( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ; )
            {
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , LocalDate.MIN );  // MIN =
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM test_";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; )
            {
                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = rs.getObject( "id_" , UUID.class );  // Pass the class to be type-safe, rather than casting returned value.
                    LocalDate localDate = rs.getObject( "date_" , LocalDate.class );  // Ditto, pass class for type-safety.

                    //Display values
                    System.out.println( "id_: " + id + " | date_: " + localDate );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> id_: 4b0ba138-d7ae-469b-854f-5cbe7430026f | date_: -999999999-01-01

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Even with 'compliant driver', the stored date is still in java.sql.date, not in LocalDate.  If you store LocalDate.MIN in your table, retrieve it would end with a date of 'id_: b8d9be62-71cc-4ea9-86e2-cb55138379d1 | date_: +169087565-03-15'

Comment: @Guangliang Nope, I do not see your problem. I get the same value when storing and retrieving [`LocalDate.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN): `-999999999-01-01`. See the new example app source code using `LocalDate.MIN` that I appended to my Answer.

Comment: For me, the `setObject` way of doing things has the problem that there is an unwanted timezone conversion in there somewhere - the date represented by the LocalDate object gets shifted back by one day (I'm in timezone GMT+1)! Is that a sign of a non-compliant driver? Or should non-compliant drivers not have the setObject method at all?

Comment: @codeling No, there is ***no* such adjustment being made with `LocalDate`** objects being stored in a SQL-standard `DATE` type column. If you store January 23rd of 2019, you’ll get back the same, absolutely.  You may be thinking of the terrible `java.sql.Date` class which *pretends* to represent a date-only but actually carries a time-of-day and UTC. Never use that legacy class.  Use only *java.time* classes for all your date-to e handling. If you see some puzzling behavior, post a new Question with example code.

Comment: yes, my fault - I missed that the database column was a DATETIME type, not a DATE. sorry for the noise!

Comment: some more experiments, and very strange results - I converted the column to DATE, and use `setObject` with the LocalDate to store, but I still get the day subtraction... I guess I'll post a new question...

Comment: @codeling Have you tried copying the example code seen in my Answer here? That is a complete example of storing and retrieving `LocalDate` objects to `DATE` column using `PreparedStatement::setObject( … , LocalDate ld );`

Comment: I tried myCallableStatement.setObject(1, myLocalDate) and it returns invalid colummn type. Using ojdbc8.jar

Comment: @Silencer310 I do not know what JDBC driver "ojdbc8.jar" is. Support for the *java.time* types is required by [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later. Check to see if your driver is out-dated.

Comment: @BasilBourque: I downloaded from here https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html. from the unzipped jdbc driver section. I am trying to find if JDBC 4.2 is supported but I am unable to do so.