# java-How should one pass a date value to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a column field called `StartDate` in MySQL of `Date` datatype. In my application, I defined a way to show the current date onn my page like this.

```
String today = CoreUtil.parseDate(new Date());
```

This basically returns the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and stored it in a string which is fine.

Now, I would like to pass this value into a function that inserts the value to the column `StartDate`.

The function I declared is as follow:

```
public void insert_update(String nodeid,String ts,Date startdt,Date enddt,int enable)
```

I am calling this function and passing the value `today` to it like below:

```
 fileFacade.insert_update(...,....,today,....,...);
```

Now I am not an expert in this date thingy and seeing it wouldn't allow me to pass the value as I defined it as Date parameter, how should I handle this issue?

Should I convert it back to Date format and pass the value or does MySQL allow insertion of string value into a Date datatype column?

I just want to store the value in my table in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

edit:

My function:

```
public void insert_update(String nodeid,String ts,Date startdt,Date enddt,int enable){
     try {

         //   UrlLink attr = em.find(UrlLink.class,n);


         String sql="UPDATE urllink SET STARTDT="+startdt+",ENDDT="+enddt+",ENABLE="+enable+"WHERE URL='f0="+nodeid+"&ts="+ts + "'";

         em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();




     }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

 }
```

Comment: Store the timestamp (long) into database.

Comment: I don't need the format to have time in my table, just in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: 1. Respect the Java naming conventions 2. Stop using Date. It's clumsy and obsolete. Use a java.time.LocalDate. 3. If a method expects a [Local]Date, you can't pass it a String. You must pass it a [Local]Date. Just don't transform the [Local]Date to a String in the first place. pass it directly. And use a prepared statement to pass the LocalDate as a parameter. You shouldn't transform the date to a string to insert it in the database.

Comment: None of the above. Don't. Don't create the date yourself. Let the database do it, with CURRENT_DATE in the SQL. And store it as a `DATE` type, not as ASCII. Simplify your life.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2). You may also find [may answer to a different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312215/5772882) useful.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use and `Date`, no matter if you mean `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As an aside I don’t understand how your `insert_update` works. I cannot see valid SQL syntax coming out of the string concatenation involving `Date` objects in the method. Maybe it’s just me.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's just a function that I call and pass in the values that I want and then it update the table based on the parameters I passed. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to convert `String` into a `Date` in order to insert it into a table. You can use `date` type as is using `preparedStatement`, e.g.:

```
Date date = new Date();
PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("<query>");
pStmt.setDate(1, date);
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) the javadoc.

**Update**

If the purpose here is to display the date in specified format then I would strongly recommend storing the date as `DATE` in MySQL in format it while querying. The decision of how we store the date should not be driven by how it needs to be displayed on Front End as we might need different date formats to be displayed across multiple User Interfaces.

Comment: But this includes hours,mins and sec too. I don't want that

Comment: It will be taken care by MySQL's date type. If you don't want hours, minutes etc in query, you can just select the date part.

Comment: Oh I'm not using preparedStatement, just want to know the correct way to pass my argument to the function

Comment: the function accepts `Date` and hence, the correct way to pass an argument to it is to pass a `Date` object. If the function accepts a date, it's upto that function to store it into MySQL.

Comment: You mean I should pass `date` directly to the function parameter?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should not bother about converting it into String.

Comment: I debug `Date date=new Date()` and it shows Mon Mar 25 though.

Comment: Is there a way I can display it as `YYYY-MM-DD` on my front end?

Comment: Yes, you can format it while fetching it from database. I would recommend not to store the date in predefined format just for display purpose.

Comment: Yea it's showing `Mon Mar 25 17:26:46 SGT 2019` on my display. Is there a way to make it show in the format i want ?

Comment: Yes, how are you fetching the date from the database?

Comment: So the problem is I want to show the date format in `YYYY-MM-DD` and also insert into database in the exact same format.

Answer (score -1):

Pass String date in method parameter instead of Date type and then format that date type like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);

formatter.parse(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. And also do keep and pass your date in a `LocalDate`, not in a `String`.