# How do I update the filed of date while I have an text view in activity

Tags: android, database, firebase, date, updates

My question is I need to update an entry from the database which is of type "date". When i created a new activity called update activity in which I used edittext as to stored the updated date. 
Now I am getting an runtime error saying cannot convert date type variable to String. My model class has an Constructor which has a field with datatype as date type. If I change the "date" to String I get an compile error saying change the fields of the constructor.

Comment: Please add your database structure, the entire error that you get and the lines of code that produces that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Comment: What is you (min) API level?