# Why is my result set in java reading my dbeaver column for date as null and how can I work around this?

Tags: java, date, null, resultset, dbeaver

Why is my result set in Java reading my DBeaver column for date as `null` and how can I work around this?

Below you can see photos showing that Java is reading my date column from DBeaver as `null` when that is not the case, as well as my prepared statement and result set in Java.

[image: Java console - can see that Java is reading my date column as null when it is not]

[image: DBeaver - can see that my date column is not null]

```
public Set<Reimbursement> getReimbursementsForEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Connection conn = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM reimbursement WHERE e_id = ?";

        Set<Reimbursement> reimbursements = new HashSet<Reimbursement>();

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, employee.getEmployeeId());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Reimbursement reimbursement = new Reimbursement();
                reimbursement.setReimbursementNumber(rs.getInt("reimbursementnumber"));
                reimbursement.setDate(rs.getDate("ddate"));
                reimbursement.setAmount(rs.getDouble("amount"));
                reimbursement.setReimbursementRequestInfo(rs.getString("reimbursementrequestinfo"));
                reimbursement.setManagerComment(rs.getString("managercomment"));
                reimbursement.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));
                reimbursement.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("e_id")); 
                reimbursement.setManagerId(rs.getInt("m_id"));

                reimbursements.add(reimbursement);
            }

            return reimbursements;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Try using rs.getString("ddate"), and then convert to the Date object using 'SimpleDateFormat'. I think the conversion is not working, and hence returning null.

Comment: thank you. I gave that a try, but Java is still reading the date as null. reimbursement.setDate(rs.getString(simpleDateFormat.format("ddate")));

Comment: Which RDBMS is under your DBeaver? (Like Oracle, MariaDB or DB2, for example.) Which datatype is your column? `date`?

Comment: MariaDB. In Java my date datatype is LocalDate. In MariaDB, my date column was created with the following syntax: ddate date not null default CURRENT_DATE,

Comment: It’s probably not answering your question, but if `reimbursement.setDate()` expects a `LocalDate` (which is good), you should use `rs.getObject("ddate", LocalDate.class)` (provided JDBC 4.2). [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Comment: amazing! thank you so much to everyone for your help! rs.getObject("ddate", LocalDate.class) works!