# Prepared statement parameter bug for "JAVA parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)"

Tags: java

I'm trying to insert a variable into the database.

Heres my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection =null;
    DBhelper helper = new DBhelper();
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    try{
        connection= helper.getConnection();

        System.out.println("baglantı olustu");

        String sql = "INSERT INTO pandemi(toplamvirus) VALUES ('?') ";
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setInt(1,2);
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        int result = statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException exception){
        helper.showErrorMessage(exception);
    }
    finally {
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }



    //String sql = "UPDATE pandemi SET toplamvirus='ff' ";





}
```

And the error is:

```
baglantı olustu
Error: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
Error code : 0
```

The database is: https://prnt.sc/rile7q

Comment: pretty sure the offsets are zero-based, i.e. the correct call is `statement.setInt(0,2);`

Comment: Use         String sql = "INSERT INTO pandemi(toplamvirus) VALUES (?)  "; without the apostrophes. It thinks your inserting the ? character

Comment: I did what you suggest. But now , here is another error :   Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? )' at line 1

Comment: @ggb667 i guess i done it.. The error is gone!!  But the variable didn't insert into database. Whatever , thank you so much

Comment: No for SQL the offsets are 1 based.  Also, you are calling update twice.          statement.executeUpdate(sql);//Do not do this, you already set SQL as the sql the statement is to process in the constructor.
int result = statement.executeUpdate();  You should eliminate the ' characters surrounding the ?

Answer (score 2):

## Pass argument ordinal and a value to `setInt`

You are incorrectly using the [`PreparedStatement::setInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,int)) method. The first argument is an ordinal number (incorrectly documented in the Javadoc as an index). So first placeholder is # 1, second placeholder is # 2, and so on. You have only a single `?` placeholder. Or were you trying to pass a value of two to be inserted into the database? Your question is not clear.

## Use naked `?`

Also, you need to remove the single-quote marks from around the `?` placeholder in your [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). Using `'?'` means you want a single-character string consisting of a question mark inserted into the database. With the single-quotes in place, you have no placeholder in your SQL statement. So your `setInt` method will fail. If using a naked `?`, the question mark will be recognized as a placeholder.

By the way, I suggest making a habit of using the SQL statement terminator, a semicolon.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO pandemi ( toplamvirus ) VALUES ( ? ) ; ";
```

For more info, see [another Answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43039615/642706) with a complete example app using the H2 database engine demonstrating `INSERT` with a placeholder in a prepared statement.

Comment: I did what you suggest. But not , i get this error :Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? )' at line 1

Comment: @Emre Print the text of your SQL to the console, and compare with other examples. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: And copy that SQL text from the console to an admin app, and run manually to eliminate Java from the question and focus on understanding proper SQL syntax.

Comment: Try the following: `String sql = "INSERT INTO pandemi ( toplamvirus ) VALUES ( ? ) ";` In other words, drop the semicolon in the string literal. (Maybe I should down-vote for an incorrect answer ;-)

Comment: @Abra You are claiming semicolon is not the statement terminator in SQL?

Comment: The SQL string you pass to a `PreparedStatement` object should not be terminated by a semicolon.