# Parse date from file using java split

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, csv, file.readalllines

I have code that parses a file then inserts the rows into a table. I ignored the first row originally because it had just the date and useless data. I want to now take the date and insert it into all the rows in my table but don't know how to really do that. I know I will need to edit my entity to include the date but don't know how to edit my code to parse the date or if its better to have a new method that does just the inserting of the date.

file format

```
20200310|extra|extra|extra||
Mn1223|01192|windows|extra|extra|extra||
Sd1223|02390|linux|extra|extra|extra||
2
```

current table

```
account_name      command_name   system_name    createDt
Mn1223            01192          windows        NULL
Sd1223            02390          linux          NULL
```

I want the `20200310` inserted into the createDt

Entity/model

```
public ZygateEntity(String accountName, String commandName, String systemName){
        this.accountName=accountName;
        this.commandName=commandName;
        this.systemName=systemName;
    }

   //getters and setters
```

Parse file method

```
   private List<ZygateEntity> parseZygateData() throws IOException {
        String filePath = "C:\\DEV\\Test_file.xlsx";

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath));

        // remove date and amount
        lines.remove(0);
        lines.remove(lines.size() - 1);

        return lines.stream()
                .map(s -> s.split("[|]")).map(val -> new ZygateEntity(val[0],val[1],val[2])).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

insert method

```
public void insertZygateData(List<ZygateEntity> parseData) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Landing.midrange_xygate_load (account_name,command_name,system_name)"+
            "VALUES (:account_name,:command_name,:system_name)";

    for (ZygateEntity zygateInfo : parseData){
        SqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource("account_name", zygateInfo.getAccountName())
                .addValue("command_name", zygateInfo.getCommandName())
                .addValue("system_name", zygateInfo.getSystemName());
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### java.time

```
    // remove date and amount
    String dateLine = lines.remove(0);
    String dateString = dateLine.split("[|]")[0];
    LocalDate date
            = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
    lines.remove(lines.size() - 1);
```

This gives you a `LocalDate` object ready to insert with every line.

java.time is the modern Java date and time API and has a built-in formatter for your date format, `20200310`: `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`.

Comment: can you show me how to then do that to my insert method if I added the 'Create_dt` in my entity file

Comment: Well, I have never heard about the `MapSqlParameterSource` class that you are using, so how to pass it a `LocalDate` I don’t know. A guess would be that adding `.addValue("createDt", zygateInfo.getCreateDate())` to your call chain should work.

Comment: thank you I figured it out by just passing `dateString` instead of `LocalDate` object then doing the same thing I did for the other parameters and just edited my `ZygateEntity` to take a 4th string

Comment: If it’s what works, then it’s good. Normally we’d prefer to keep our date as a `LocalDate` and also pass that to the database (see for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)), but if your framework cannot do that, …