# Value of Date type is getting icremented by 1 month

Tags: java, java.util.date

I am trying to take a variable of Date type . But output I am getting is automatically getting incremented by one month.
Here is what I am doing

```java
Date d1 = new Date(2020,8,15);
System.out.println(d1);
```

d1's value is coming `2020-09-15` instead of `2020-08-15`.

Comment: Yes we have to write 8 instead of 08, I have edited the code in the question.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If you necessarily need a `Date`, create as `Date.from(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.AUGUST, 15).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())`. Under no circumstances use the 3-arg `Date` constructor. It has been deprecated since early 1997.

Comment: Or if you need a `java.sql.Date` — you probably don’t, you can transfer the `LocalDate` to your SQL database, see [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: For now my issue was solved. But as you said it will be a better approach to use LocalDate. I will use it further instead of using Date. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` takes months from 0 to 11 and not 1 to 12. So, `new Date(2020,08,15);` is actually `15th September 2020`

And when date is printed/formatted, actual month is printed (values 1 to 12).
According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

**Note** : Always prefer [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) over `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, month values are starting at `0`, which makes an `8` be September when using the outdated API (e.g. `java.util.Date`).

That means to get the desired output, you would have to write (without a leading zero)

```
Date d1 = new Date(2020, 9, 15);
System.out.println(d1);
```

Fortunately, there's `java.time` now!

You can use it like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 15);
    System.out.println(d1);
}
```

and it outputs

```
2020-08-15
```