# Java String to DateTime parse issue

Tags: java, string, datetime-format

I have a record which have an abnormal DateTime String '20170-09-17',I tried to parse it into DateTime but it didn't throw any Exceptions and this record can not put into MySQL as well...

```
        DateFormat fmt =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(fmt.parse("20170-09-17"));
```

What to do with this data?

Comment: That won't ever be a valid date. You need to remove that 0.

Comment: @WrightsCS  Did you read his question properly?  He himself told it's not a valid date  but the parsing is okay which ideally shouldn't.   You din't understood his question properly..

Comment: @Stunner which is why I said "You need to remove that 0".

Comment: I don't think I can remove it if I can't validate it.

Comment: @WrightsCS  I guess he meant if he inputs invalid date , he is expecting a parse exception instead the program continues fine without any exception.

Comment: @DodgeXiong  Read this https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-regular-expressions. Use regular expression , pattern match to validate your date.

Comment: @Stunner that is helpful,Thanks for you both.

Comment: I would recommend not using `SimpleDateFormat` to start with and in instead use the `DateTimeFormatter` from the `java.time` APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` doesn't know the supported range of year where the date will be stored, so ***you*** need to validation the date.

Since you mentioned MySQL, and the [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) data type supports years in range 1000-9999, you should do this:

```java
static Date parseDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    // Parse the string (strict)
    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    fmt.setLenient(false); // Reject invalid month and day values
    Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
    
    // Validate year
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (year < 1000 || year > 9999)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid year: \"" + dateStr + "\"");
    
    return date;
}
```

The important parts are:

- Turn on strict parsing mode, to ensure `month` and `day` values are in valid ranges.
- Custom check to ensure `year` value is in valid range.

---

It might be better if you could use the newer Java 8+ Time API, in which case the code would be:

```java
static LocalDate parseDate(String dateStr) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, fmt);
    if (date.getYear() < 1000 || date.getYear() > 9999)
        throw new DateTimeException("Invalid value for Year (valid values 1000 - 9999): " + date.getYear());
    return date;
}
```

Same as before: Strict parsing and custom year range check.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I always recommend to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for date work. In this case it makes your task pretty simple.

```
    String abnormalInput = "20170-09-17";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(abnormalInput);
    System.out.println(date);
```

This throws the exception that you had expected:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
> Text '20170-09-17' could not be parsed at index 0

We don’t even need to specify any formatter. Your expected input is in ISO 8601 format (link at the bottom), and `LocalDate` parses ISO 8601 as its default. And throws an exception if the text to parse does not adhere to the format. It *can* accept a year with more than four digits, but then only with a sign (minus or plus). Because the standard says so.

The range check that Andreas suggests in his answer could still be a good idea. I suggest that you set the limits not by what MySQL can handle but by what can be considered correct in your domain. For the sake of an example:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"));
    if (date.getYear() < today.getYear() - 5 || date.isAfter(today)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Date is out of range: " + date);
    }
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Question: Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Comment: Very well answered! Both the points (regarding the exception in formatting and regarding the validation of the year) provide with the recommended way to solve this problem. The first point, `We don’t even need to specify any formatter.` is spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat and Date are outdated classes. If you use java 8 or higher please switch to [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class and classes like [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) or any of their "brothers"

Comment: Though maybe rather a comment than an answer this is very good advice.