# How to convert sql date format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format

Hello I am trying to convert sql date format to "dd-MM-yyyy" but in the output I have this unwanted format which shows the current date time (Mon Aug 14 00.00....)

```
String inputDate  = rs.getDate("BIRTH_DATE").toString();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date outputDate = formatter.parse(inputDate);
user.setBirthdate(outputDate);
```

Comment: Call `parse` not on the result of `toString()`, call it on the result of rs.getDate itself.

Comment: Incompatible types : Date cannot be converted to String

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also see [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: Right, given today’s date (2021-02-14), your code gives Mon Aug 14 00:00:00 CET 19, that’s 2001 years 6 months ago. A surprise alright.

Answer (score 0):

Dates do not have an inherent format.

```
java.util.Date inputDate = rs.getDate("BIRTH_DATE");
user.setBirthdate(inputDate);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String representation = formatter.format(inputDate);
```

It would be better to use the new java.time classes: `LocalDate, ZonedDateTime` and so on.