# How To Insert Oracle Date Data type in Java

Tags: java, oracle

**Hello everybody**,

I am newbie in java. I tried to create such a data pipe line that copy tables from 1 source to different servers & databases. It work fine with String and Number, but I stuck in Date datatype. I got ***Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month***.

I have no idea how to change the date format in java or work with date data type.

Here the detail :
Oracle 10g (Svr1) & 11g (Svr2), java 8 with ojdbc14.jar

The table's DB

```
Table = LAB
field = ID(INT), LAB_DESC(VARCHAR2, 50), LAB_DATE(DATE)
```

The Java Code

```
//========= Bismillah Arrahman Arrahiem =============//
//============== DARI SINI ========================================//
//    **    **  **  **
//  ****    **  **  **     ****        ** ** **     ** 
//  ****    **  **  **     *  *        ** ** **     **
//     **********   **   ****************************
//                                             *
//
//========================= LAB =============================//
package simpledtpipeline;
import java.sql.*;
public class SimpleDTpipeline {

     public static void main(String[] args) 
       //========= Bismillah =============//
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, Exception {
 // Load the JDBC driver
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
 System.out.println("Driver loaded");
//======================================================// 
 // Connect to a database
Connection connectionServer1 = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.7.1:1521:dbone", "user", "pass123");
 System.out.println("Database 192.168.7.1 connected");
//======================================================//
Connection connectionServer2 = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.7.2:1521:dbtwo", "user2", "pass789");
System.out.println("Database 192.168.7.2 connected");
//
//========================= LAB =============================//
Statement SelectLAB = connectionServer1.createStatement();
// Execute a statement
 ResultSet FetchLAB = SelectLAB.executeQuery
("SELECT ID, LAB_DESC, LAB_DATE from LAB ");
//*****************************************************************//
PreparedStatement InsertLAB = connectionServer2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO LAB "
        + "(ID, LAB_DESC, LAB_DATE) VALUES (?,?, TO_DATE(?,'MM/DD/YYYY')");
while (FetchLAB.next()){
    InsertLAB.setInt(1,FetchLAB.getInt("ID")); 
    InsertLAB.setString(2,FetchLAB.getString("LAB_DESC")); 
    InsertLAB.setString(3,FetchLAB.getString("LAB_DATE")); 
    InsertLAB.execute(); 
}
//======================================================//
//
// Close the connection //
 connectionServer1.close();
 connectionServer2.close();
}
       
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```java
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(                                           // Use `setObject` for java.time types.
    3 ,                                               // Third placeholder in the Question's example text.
    LocalDate                                         // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .parse(
        "01/23/2020" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" )   // Specify formatting codes for your particular text input’s format. Case-sensitive.
    )
)
```

## Formatting codes

I am guessing that the specific problem in your code is incorrect formatting codes: `'MM/DD/YYYY'`. I do not know Oracle Database codes, but I would guess they are case-sensitive, as seen in other such tooling. If so, you may be using the wrong case. Or your formatting codes do not match the actual text of your inputs.

Either way, the issue is moot. You should be passing Java objects for your date-time values instead of plain text.

## Use date-time objects in Java

You date-time objects on the Java side, rather than mere strings.

Use only the *java.time* classes in Java, never the legacy classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

[JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) requires a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to support a subset of the *java.time* types.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

But unfortunately and mysteriously, the spec does *not* provide type-specific `set…` methods for the *java.time* types. Instead, we use `setObject` on the prepared statement, and `getObject` on the result set.

```java
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```java
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

If your inputs are text in the format of month/day/year numbers, parse into `LocalDate` objects. Trap for `DateTimeParseException` in case of faulty inputs.

```
String input = "01/23/2022" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , format ) ;
```

Using localized formats for such text in data-exchange is a poor practice. I suggest you educate the publisher of that textual data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format for dates: YYYY-MM-DD. So January 23 of 2022 would be `2022-01-23`.

## Unrelated tips

Calling `Class.forName` to load a JDBC driver is old-school. No longer necessary for modern Java.

Generally advised to use a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation for your particular database rather to hold info to make database connections. Your JDBC driver should provide such an implementation.

The JDBC resources such as [`Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html) and [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) implement the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface. This means we can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close these resources while simplifying our code.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: I had trying
```
InsertLAB.setObject(                    // Use `setObject` for java.time types.
    3 ,                                               // Third placeholder in the Question's example text.
    LocalDate                                         // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .parse(
        FetchLAB.getString("LAB_DATE") , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" )   // Specify formatting codes for your particular text input’s format. Case-sensitive.
    )
);  
```

Comment: and got this message

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-02-24 00:00:00.0' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
 at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
 at simpledtpipeline.SimpleDTpipeline.main(SimpleDTpipeline.java:42)
C:\Users\Handiki-Shinta\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Handiki-Shinta\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Very good answer. It may worth mentioning that with `setObject()` we need the SQL to be `INSERT INTO LAB (ID, LAB_DESC, LAB_DATE) VALUES (?,?, ?);` with no call to `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: thank a lot for your reply & knowledge share @Basil Bourque