# How to compare year in streams without using getYear()?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am currently working with streams in Java. I am creating a list which stores table values as an object from MySQL.

I want to filter the contents by comparing with a year in the filter. However, the date column in the table has the format `dd-mm-yyy`. When I try to compare by using `getYear()` with my input year, for example `2018`, it is showing an wrong output (I know getYear() has been deprecated).

How to compare two dates using streams which is in the format `dd-mm-yyy`?

Below contains the code snippet I am working with:

```java
public List<Payment> findCustomerByYear(int year){
    List<Payment> list1 = paymentDao.getAllRecord();
    List<Payment> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    list2 = list1.stream()
                 .filter(i -> i.getPaymentDate().getYear() == year)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return list2;
}
```

Is there any other option to compare dates instead of using `getYear()` in `list2`?

Comment: What is reported error and what does `getPaymentDate()` return?

Comment: Convert to a ZonedDateTime and call getYear(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

Comment: btw `List<Payment> list2 = new ArrayList<>();` is wasteful as it assigns a newly created ArrayList which is then immediately thrown away.

Comment: @Tom. It showing getYear() was deprecated. getPaymentDate() is just a getter method to retrieve date for that particular object

Comment: @keuleJ. It contains more than one object and all the comparisons need to done in that stream only. Can you give me a example ?

Comment: getYear() being deprecated is not an error. It's a warning. I suspect your error is that you are comparing a value such as 121 returned from getYear(), with 2021. The documentation for getYear() describes what it does.

Comment: @k314159. Yes it was returning 121. Then how to convert into full year.

Comment: @k314159. list2 = list1.stream().filter(i->(i.getPaymentDate().getYear()+1900)==year).collect(Collectors.toList()); is it correct now ?

Comment: Yes that looks correct. Although, as getPaymentDate() returns a Date, which is a legacy type, it may be worth the effort to change it to return a modern replacement such as LocalDate or ZonedDateTime.

Comment: @k314159. Thank you. Sure i will change it

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` (no matter if that was `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`). Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You can directly get a `LocalDate` from MySQL, see [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Answer (score 3):

A `DATE` column in MySQL has no “format” because it is not text.

You should fix whatever tooling is retrieving data from the database for export to a text file. That tooling is creating the text in that format. That tooling should instead be using the YYYY-MM-DD format defined by both the SQL standard and the ISO 8601 standard.

If fixing that tooling is not feasible, use `DateTimeFormatter` with a custom formatting pattern to match your text, to produce [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects. This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Never use the `java.sql.Date` and `java.until.Date` classes. These terrible classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

[image]

For more info, see [*Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43039614/642706).