# why a valid date insertion throws java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month oracle java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, exception

i am trying to insert date value  into the oracle database but its throw
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
the weirdest thing that happened, when i open oracle dashboard and i execute the same query into sql commands its work perfectly but when try to execute the query from java it launch  the exception

this is my code

```
try {
        
            Connection con=Connexion.getConnection();
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
            String ddebut=formatter.format(dateDebut);
            String dfin=formatter.format(dateFin);

            System.out.println(ddebut);
            System.out.println(dfin);
            String query ="INSERT INTO Intervention (titre,lieu,etat,description,datedebut,datefin,ide) VALUES ('"+titre+"','"+lieu+"','"+etat+"','"
                    +description+"','"+ddebut+"','"+dfin+"',"+cin+")";
            System.out.println(query);

            test=stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(dateDebut));
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select intervention_seq.currval from DUAL");
            rs.next();
            id=rs.getInt(1);
        
        
            con.close();  
        
    

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
        return test==1;
    }
```

im sure that the problem come from the query and all values of attribute are correct

is there a way to solve this problem ?[image]

Comment: Two recommendations: (1) Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) Don’t pass date as a string to Oracle. Pass a `LocalDate` and format won’t matter. See [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: Also concatenating values into your SQL statement makes it liable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use `?` plaveholders and parameter values as explained in [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle accepts date formatted in DD-MON-RR (sometimes DD-MON-YYYY) by default. However, you've specified MM/dd/YYYY.

**Solution 1**
You can simply fix this by changing the date format from this, 
`new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY")`
to this,
`new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy")` (If the default format is DD-MON-RR)
or this,
`new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")` (If the default format is DD-MON-YYYY)

Note: You can check the default format simply by just `select sysdate from dual;` and see what does it returns. If it shows something like `01-MAY-21`, then the default date format for your Oracle should be DD-MON-RR.

**Solution 2** 
Keep your SimpleDateFormat, but changes the date format at your SQL statement by using `to_date('date here', "MM/DD/YYYY")`

Comment: thank you for your answer it was very helpful , i tried the first solution and  it solve my problem the SYSDATE in oracle was 05/02/2021 not the same  format but it works

Comment: The default date format varies by region. I don't know Java but surely you don't need to pass all values as strings?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You are correct, passing date values as strings is the discouraged way (since JDBC 4.2 you should prefer to pass `LocalDate` objects).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I didn't know about this. Out of curiosity, may I ask actually why should we prefer `LocalDate` over date strings in SQL? Is it because of performance issue?

Comment: @daoern Partly for the same reasons why you use `int` rather than `String` for a whole number: It reduces the risk of errors, is makes the code more self explanatory and it offers a range of operations that you may not need at the moment but may need some other time. Also the use of `LocalDate` would completely have prevented the problem that the OP is asking about. These considerations are far more important than performance in 19 out of 20 cases. So while formatting the string and parsing it back behind the scenes in the database does cost, this is a minor point in the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost surely an NLS issue. Try supplying your dates as '20/05/2021' and '19/05/2021'. Each client (for example, Oracle dashboard and your Java program are two different clients) can have different NLS settings. These govern, among other things, the default date and time formatting.

Comment: first of all thank you for your reply , when i execute this query in oracle to get the format SELECT
  value
FROM
  V$NLS_PARAMETERS
WHERE
  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'; it display mm/dd/yyyy and i have tried many format but the problem still exist.