# How to store user input date and pass them in sql query

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime

In order to make our code more usable.
here I try to take many pattern but didn't get my results

I am however facing a problem with the date variable , If I pass static variable then it's right output. but I want to dynamic(user input date). I don't to pass predefine date.

Pls give me proper solution.

Here is the code:

```
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:VASVMT","scott","tiger");


        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter DOB (dd-mm-yyyy) format");
        String td=sc.next();
        SimpleDateFormat date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        System.out.println(date1);
        java.util.Date tdd=date1.parse(td);
        System.out.println(tdd);
        long ms=tdd.getTime();
        System.out.println(ms);
        java.sql.Date dttt=new java.sql.Date(ms);
        System.out.println(dttt);
         
        
        String sql="select * from tbl_transaction_new where to_char(date_time,'dd-mm-yyyy')='dttt'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()) {
              
               System.out.print(" NAME: "+rs.getString("messgae"));
            
        
               System.out.print(" Date: "+rs.getDate("date_time"));
             
               System.out.println();
    
        
    con.close();
    }
```

My sql table -- Like

message(column) and date_time(column, datatype- Date).. In date_time column values are like 05-JUL-2021 , 08-JUL-2021 , 01-JAN-2021.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: Your code seems to process the user input, `td`. What are you missing?

Comment: Friend, it’s a good idea to keep an eye on your question the first few hours after you’ve posted and edit it immediately in response to any requests for clarification. The interest is greatest at this time, so it increases your chances of a good reception and good answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.
2. Don’t convert back and forth between date objects, strings and longs. Parse your user input string *once* into a `LocalDate` and stick to `LocalDate` for the rest. Also you don’t need `to_char` in SQL.
3. Use a `?` parameter placeholder in your SQL and substitute the actual parameter from Java.
4. Move `con.close();` outside the loop, or you may only be able to read the first row.

In code:

```
    String userInput = "06-09-1987"; // = sc.next();
    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(userInput, DTF);
    
    String sql = "select * from tbl_transaction_new where date_time = ?;";
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setObject(1, dob);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.print(" NAME: " + rs.getString("messgae"));
        System.out.print(" Date: " + rs.getObject("date_time", LocalDate.class));
        System.out.println();
    }
    con.close();
```

The code uses the following date formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DTF = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
```

I haven’t got Oracle installed so have not had an opportunity to test myself. I have compiled the code. Please forgive if there’s a typo that wasn’t caught in compilation.

Note how I am also retrieving a `LocalDate` rather than an old-fashioned `java.sql.Date` from the result set. Passing `LocalDate` or other java.time types to and from SQL requires JDBC 4.2. About all of us have that nowadays.

Edit: You further asked:

> I have an issue with table data .. If column (date_time) value is like
> 05-JUL-201 (Type - Date) . in that case we need to use to_char
> variable or not(?)

`05-JUL-2021` is Oracle’s way of *displaying* the date in response to a query. It has nothing to do with how the date is *stored internally* in the database. It’s easier both for you and for the database to compare two dates without converting them to `char` first. So no, don’t use `to_char` (again said without having tested).

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: First of all thanks ,   I have an issue with table data .. If     column  (date_time)  value is like 05-JUL-201 (Type - Date) . in that case we need to use to_char variable or not .

Comment: @AMITPATEL Thanks for the follow-up question. Please see my edit.

Comment: @AMITPATEL I’m curious to know whether the answer turned out to be helpful and whether there’s anything I can still contribute?