# While parsing date with upper case month name I get java.time.format.DateTimeParseException

Tags: java-8, java-time, datetimeformatter

I have few lines of code as shown below

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.getDefault() );  
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("11-NOV-20", formatter);
```

Which gives below exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11-NOV-20' could not be parsed at index 3
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
        at src.DateTimeTest.main(DateTimeTest.java:30)
```

If I change the Month from **NOV** to **Nov** it works fine. I am getting this value from the database table. Do I have to change it programatically or there is any way to handle it?

Comment: You are getting that value from a database table? Don’t transfer strings between your database and your Java application. Transfer `LocalDate` objects. See [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: Also assuming that your database strings are always in English, don’t use `Locale.getDefault()` for your formatter. Use `Locale.ROOT` (or another English-speaking locale).

Comment: It is a legacy system and in that it uses java.util.Date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can configure your `DateTimeFormatter` to ignore cases

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy")
                .toFormatter(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Super. It worked like charm. Thank you.