# Zoned Date Time cannot be parsed

Tags: java, java-time

I am trying to parse this timestamp "26-JUL-23 10.01.51.336231000 AM UTC" to a ZonedDateTime object:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("26-JUL-23 10.01.51.336231000 AM UTC", formatter)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '26-JUL-23 10.01.51.336231000 AM UTC
```

I tried adding a DateTimeFormatter like this, but it is not working:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z")
```

Am I using the wrong date pattern?

Comment: Your value has 9 subsecond digits. Your pattern has 6. I strongly suspect you also want HH instead of hh, and you probably want to specify a Locale.

Comment: Month is case sensitiive you can call .parseCaseInsensitive() + subseconds fix from above. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/68364049/9248765

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse case-insensitive strings with JSR-310 DateTimeFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797808/how-to-parse-case-insensitive-strings-with-jsr-310-datetimeformatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a z")
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);/* or else*/
ZonedDateTime.parse("26-JUL-23 10.01.51.336231000 AM UTC", formatter);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you!