# How to retrieve date from database

Tags: json, database, postgresql, date, localdate

I have a column in my database that is of type DATE.
I inserted the date via Java using the method: Date.valueOF(LocalDate.now()).

```
r.setRkd(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
```

The entry is correct because the exact date appears in the table.

```
    rkd
------------
 2022-03-02
```

The problem is that when I call the service I don't get the correct date back in the JSON, but a series of numbersenter code here.

```
"rkd": 1646175600000
```

Do you know how I can print the correct date in my JSON?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's coming back as a UNIX timestamp with millisecond precision, so you want to find a datetime constructor that can handle such an input.

Comment: Since you can use `LocalDate` from the modern Java date and time API, I suggest you don’t also use the old and poorly designed `java.sql.Date`. java.time gives you everything you want, and your JDBC driver should support it too. See [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Answer (score 1):

That number you are getting is the `milliseconds` equivalent to the date you have stored. As far as I know, dates, in general, are stored as `milliseconds` and displayed in different formats, e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD`

If you need to display it in date format there should be a method to do it depending on the specific language that you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @coses and @snakecharmerb !! I used a method that converted my Date in LocalDate.
Now I have an array, but I can convert it simply! Thank you again!!
```