# Convert Mon yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd format in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I am sending date (August 2022) from java as a string to oracle plsql and i want to change the format from August 2022 to 01-08-22 in plsql. how can i do it ?

below is a part of code:

```
 PROCEDURE CHECK_DUMMY
(
        IN_SL_NO                         IN      SIGN.SL_NO%TYPE,
        IN_MONTH                    IN      SIGN.MONTH%TYPE
)
AS
    
        V_MON              DATE := TO_DATE(IN_MONTH , 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: Don’t send a string from Java. Send a `LocalDate` object. See [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: yes i did that and that worked for me. but this is the requirement how can i achieve the solution in this way

Comment: If you're passing a string like 'August 2022' you need to use this format 'Month yyyy'. It supposes that the columns MONTH in table SIGN is of type VARCHAR2.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the format model `Month YYYY` and specify the language you are using:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE CHECK_DUMMY
(
  IN_SL_NO IN SIGN.SL_NO%TYPE,
  IN_MONTH IN SIGN.MONTH%TYPE
)
AS
  V_MON DATE := TO_DATE(IN_MONTH , 'Month YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English');
BEGIN
  -- Do Something
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_mon );
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  CHECK_DUMMY(1, 'August 2022');
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```
2022-08-01 00:00:00
```

*Note: In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type comprising of 7 bytes that represent century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds and always has those 7 components and is never stored with any particular format. If you want to output `01-08-22` for display purposes then use `TO_CHAR(v_mon, 'DD-MM-YY')` to convert the date to a formatted string.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o0GtPdts)