# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column is of type date but expression is of type integer: cannot write date into postgres using java

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to insert a record inside my table but I cannot insert any values into the Date column.

This is the code I use to make an insert:

```
Connection connection = DatabaseConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
    ResultSet result = null;
    try
    {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(query,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        result = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        return result;
    }
```

How I call this function:

```
String authorName = "Paul"
String authorSurname = "Mac"
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" ) ; 
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse ( "2017-09-24" , f );

"Insert into autore(nome_autore, cognome_autore, datanascita) values('"+authorName+"', '"+authorSurname+"', "+date+")")
```

The fullstack trace I get:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "datanascita" is of type date but expression is of type integer
  Suggerimento: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Posizione: 90
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1259)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1240)
    at projectRiferimentiBibliografici/com.ProjectRiferimentiBibliografici.DatabaseConnection.QueryManager.executeUpdateWithResultSet(QueryManager.java:113)
    at projectRiferimentiBibliografici/com.ProjectRiferimentiBibliografici.DAOImplementation.AuthorDaoPostgresql.insertAuthor(AuthorDaoPostgresql.java:136)
    at projectRiferimentiBibliografici/com.ProjectRiferimentiBibliografici.Main.MainCe.main(MainCe.java:43)
```

Comment: *apparently* `2017-09-24` (the standard format of `LocalDate`) is not a valid date for PostgreSQL, it is more two subtractions resulting in `1984`. Check the correct DB format for literal dates... or use `PreparedStatement` - also recommended to avoid SQL injection (see also [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Comment: Use `?` placeholders in your SQL and your problem will be solved and you have protected yourself against SQL injection at the same time. Please see [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2).

Comment: Do **not** concatenate parameters into SQL strings. Use a `PreparedStatement` then you can pass the `LocalDate` instance directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution to this problem is to use a `PreparedStatement` - do not concatenate parameters into SQL strings.

Your problem with the date parameter is only the tip of the iceberg. 
The next problem you'll get is, if `Peter O'Donnel` signs up.

So you should use something like this:

```java
String authorName = "Paul";
String authorSurname = "Mac";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2017-09-24", f);

String insert = "Insert into autore(nome_autore, cognome_autore, datanascita) values(?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pstmt.setString(1, authorName);
pstmt.setString(2, authorSurname);
pstmt.setObject(3, date, java.sql.Types.DATE);

pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You could drop the `DateTimeFormatter`, that one is the default format.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using direct insert sql statement. As you are appending date object to string it will be converted to date.toString() which might not be expected format in sql.

Below is the insert sql statement:

```
"Insert into autore(nome_autore, cognome_autore, datanascita)
values('"+authorName+"', '"+authorSurname+"', '2017-09-24')")
```

Note: This approach of sql query building is not recommended and open to SQL Injection. Better to use PreparedStatement or an ORM framework.

Comment: Not recommended. Still open to SQL injection. Bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  way to solve this. In the place Where is you specify the jdbc url.

Ex:

```
"jdbc:postgresql://host/schema"
```

Change above to

```
"jdbc:postgresql://host/schema?stringtype=unspecified"
```

Then your db determine type of your params not the jdbc driver.

Comment: I haven’t tried it. Have you? I don’t expect it to help.

Comment: Yes I tried it in springboot and it worked. But not 100% sure in this context.

Comment: https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/pgjdbc/42.2.1/connect.html refer this link.

Comment: But in my case I use prepared statements. Because as you mentioned it is the best way. As I remember even I do that I have to change the jdbc url as above.

Comment: That’s what I meant. While your suggestion is probably a good one, if it hasn’t got an effect with the OP’s code, then it doesn’t answer this question.