# Java Spring Boot Date Value Changed After Parsing

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, rest, date

I'm trying to create a REST API with Java Spring Boot, and currently writing JUnit test cases on it.

It appears that, given an entity containing a `java.sql.Date` instance, after saving it to the database and responding with the returned value of `save()`, the date value is no longer the same.

After double-checking, I'm indeed using `java.sql.Date` everywhere, not `java.util.Date`.

I'm using PostgreSQL and Hibernate for database management.

Here's the problematic code:

```java
        Booking createdBooking = new Booking(
                new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
                ..., // rest of the arguments are not important for the discussion
        );

        ResponseEntity<BookingDto> response = client.postForEntity(
                "/createBooking",
                BookingDto.toDTO(createdBooking),
                BookingDto.class);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());

        assertNotNull(response.getBody());

        assertEquals(createdBooking.getCheckInDate(), response.getBody().getCheckInDate());
```

Here's the controller implementation:

```java
    @PostMapping(value = { "/createBooking", "/createBooking/" })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public BookingDto createBooking(@RequestBody BookingDto bookingDto) {
        Booking booking = bookingService.createBooking(bookingDto);
        return BookingDto.toDTO(booking);
    }
```

Here's the simplified service implementation:

```java
    public Booking createBooking(BookingDto bookingDto) {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        booking.setCheckInDate(bookingDto.getCheckInDate());
        // rest of the arguments are not important for the discussion
        return bookingRepository.save(booking);
    }
```

As for the `Booking` class, the default constructor is empty.

The assertion fails on the one to check if the dates are equal. The output is:

```
Expected :2023-11-06
Actual   :2023-11-04
```

`2023-11-06` being the actual GMT and local time when I run the test, `2023-11-04` I don't know why.

I've looked at several posts regarding using `SimpleDateFormat`, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948209/why-converting-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date-results-in-a-wrong-date) for example, but I believe my case is a bit different because my date value literally "changed" after having a run through the database.

I'm looking for help to explain why this behavior occurs, and how can I make sure the date values will be consistent. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

Project has been initialized with [Spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with Spring Boot 3.1.4 and Java 17, both compatible with my system.

Reading/writing to database are handled by the `BookingRepository`, which extends `CrudRepository` and thus injected by Spring:

```java
public interface BookingRepository extends CrudRepository<Booking, Integer> {
...
```

And I didn't define any explicit conversion or synchronization beside the application properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hotel_management
spring.datasource.username={omitted}
spring.datasource.password={omitted}
```

**EDIT 2:**

After digging further, I find out that the problem comes from the date conversion, as the `java.sql.Date` instance on the client's side is parsed to the last GMT time value at 12:00:00 AM, but the server's side receives the same value but take it as a local time value in its `java.sql.Date` instance, which is 5 hours off. After rounding, the date would be off by a day. The same process happens vice-versa.

Still trying to figure out how to solve it while keep using `java.sql.Date`, as switching to other data types isn't very much an option in my case.

Comment: Are the time and Date of the server and the database synchronized?
How are you reading the Booking from the DB ? are you making any type of conversion?

Comment: @DavidA. I just added some info to the question. LMK if that answers your question.

Comment: It looks everything set as should be, and i could proceed asking for more data, but lets try something else, could you change the `date` (that is a little old) to `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`? and then you could set `new Booking(LocalDateTime.now())`

Comment: Any chance you have the date sent without timezones, but saved in timezone included format DB side? Just trying to brainstorm here.

Comment: @DavidA. The `Booking` model was made with Umple model, which defaults to using `java.sql.Date`. Changing the date type would require me to go over many files and I tend not to do that unless it's my very last option.
However, check my new edit for more info.

Comment: @mrxaxen the problem looks more like a client-server parsing issue rather than DB issue. See my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the application to UTC time seems to work.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316667/how-do-i-force-a-spring-boot-jvm-into-utc-time-zone) for how to do it.