# How to insert a date (12-dec-2020) from excel to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, excel, date

i got the data from in excel file and pet it into an array string, the date is in the format (12/12/2020) whine i print it withe the method toString() i get (12-dec-2020), and when i tried simpledateformat codes that i found i get the errors "unparseable date java" or "SimpleDateFormat Cannot format given Object as a Date" or "The import java.text.SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved"can anyone help me please?
my code:

```
for (int row =0;row<sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;row ++) {
XSSFRow erow = sheet.getRow(row);
for(int column =0;column<sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();column++) {
XSSFCell ecolumn = erow.getCell(column);
exdata[row][column]= String.valueOf(ecolumn);
    }
} 
String stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").format(exdata[1][5].toString());
Date date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(stringDate);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(date));
```

Comment: The Excel format appears to be `dd-MMM-yyyy`, but you may have issues with the fact that the month is in lower case.  You should also be making use of `LocalDate` and the associated `java.time.*` APIs over the `java.util.*` based date/time APIs

Comment: I strongly recommend that you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes were troublesome and are fortunately long outdated. Can’t you simply use [`XSSFCell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getLocalDateTimeCellValue--)?

Comment: I suggest that this is partially a duplicate of [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2). For converting the `LocalDateTime` from the cell to a `LocalDate` (without time of day), simply use `ecolumn.getLocalDateTime().toLocalDate()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by making use of the `java.time.*` APIs over the, out-of-date, effectively deprecated, `java.util.*` date/time APIs.

Next, the Excel format seems to be in `dd-MMM-yyy` not, `MM/yyyy`.  You may also have issues because the month is in lower case, lucky, there's a relatively easy way to get around this...

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")
        .toFormatter();
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("12-dec-2020", formatter);
```

Inserting the value into MySQL shouldn't be complicated, but will depend on the column data type.  If you're using `Date` (as the column type - no I'm not a MySQL expert), then you can use something like `java.sql.Date.valueOf(ld);` to get a SQL `Date` which you could use as part of a `PreparedStatement`.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2), *"JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers can deal directly with `java.time` objects"*, so even better, just bind the `ld` object to the `PreparedStatement`!

If the column is `text`, then you're doing it wrong.