# How i can get the current date from java android application and store it in mysql DB if phone language arabic or english

Tags: java, android, mysql, date

In my Android app I need to get the current date and insert it into MySQL DB. The issue is that when the phone language is English, everything is OK, but if it is in Arabic, the date is inserted as 0000-00-00

I tried to find a way to convert the date format before inserting to DB as English but nothing happened.

```java
public String getTime() {
    Date dt = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String CurrentTime = sdf.format(dt);
    return CurrentTime;
  }
```

Comment: Your question has no code at all. Please show us what you already have done so we can help from that

Comment: Use english locale: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: i tried that but also not working

Comment: I warn against using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Thiose classes were troublesome and therefore were supplanted by [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) a decade ago. While I am not sure about Android, on desktop Java you can use `LocalDate` in Java and store it into a column of type `date` in MySQL. I expect it to work the same on newer Android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes. Do not use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

> if phone language arabic or english

Arabic versus English should be irrelevant.

> get the current date

Get the current date as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now() ;
```

Specify time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) ;
```

> and insert it in MySQL DB

Define your column to be of the `DATE` type in MySQL. For date-time values, use date-time types, not text/strings.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject ( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```