# MariaDB-java-connector with MySQL 5.7 database not support DATE type

Tags: hikaricp, mysql-5.7, mariadb-connect-engine

- SpringBoot: 2.7.13
- HikariCP: 4.0.3
- MariaDB-java-connector: 2.0.1-3.2.0
- MySQL 5.7 in (wix-embedded-mysql: 4.6.2)

A simple attempt to insert data of the DATE type into a database results in an error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not convert [2018-11-22] to 91
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getSqlException(ExceptionMapper.java:192)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePrepareStatement.setInternalObject(BasePrepareStatement.java:1030)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.BasePrepareStatement.setObject(BasePrepareStatement.java:833)
```

I don't know where to find a solution to a problem with HikariCP or MariaDB-java-connector settings. I know that DATE is deprecated, but is there a way to support old databases?

Comment: Sure. Insert a modern `LocalDate` into your column of type `date`. [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2). And while `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` are long outdated, I would still happily use `date` in MySQL.